# Custom email attachment in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, email-attachments, uidocument

I'm working on developing an ipad app that has the following elements:

Albums

Images (all images are within albums, there can obviously be many images in one album)

Audio (audio is associated to specific images, there can be multiple audio files associated to one images)

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a "document structure" that supports two things: 1) sending an image via email while retaining the attached audio such that the recipient can open the attachment in the app on their own ipad, 2) downloading entire albums from within the app such that the images and their associated audio are intact.

I'm looking into using UIDocument but would love any input/advice/pointers to tutorials to make sure I'm going down the right path..

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to send an email with all the audio files attached, or the audio files stay on your server?

Comment: I'd like the audio files attached (or, rather, embedded in the custom attachment)

Comment: Have you considered leaving the resources on your server and then sending only a notification via email? Then the recipient could then open the app and download the files from your server. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, just trying to figure out whether that's going to be considerable amount more effort (setting up / maintaining the server, managing the client / server communication to make sure downloads are happening completely, etc). Are there tools that make that easier?